# Why in some situations comes ing?

Tags: verbs, infinitive-vs-gerund

In the following sentence:

> The governor's assistant claimed to have unique psychic abilities
>   **enabling** him to read people's minds.

How can we know to use a verb with ing form? Like "enabling" in the above sentence. Why we cannot say: "... psychic abilities (that) enable him ..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *Enabling* is a gerund

When you see a verb used like this that ends with *-ing*:

> like enabling him to read people's minds.

This is called a gerund. The verb *enabling* is actually functioning as a noun in this instance. All gerunds end with *-ing* just like the present participle.

It is completely acceptable to say either of these:

> The governor's assistant claimed to have unique psychic abilities **enabling** him to read people's minds.
>
> The governor's assistant claimed to have unique psychic abilities **that enable** him to read people's minds.